# Improving the [management] tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wikis

In the spirit of my [last post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6210/5652) about improving the tag wikis, I’m nominating [management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management) as the first <s>victim</s> <s>target</s> *opportunity*.

[management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management) is a good place to get started because:

- It’s a very active tag (in the top 5)
- The tag wiki and excerpt are both light
- We can (and should) explicitly decide if “the management” (i.e., the managers of a firm) is an appropriate use of the tag
- Some great questions and answers are tagged [management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management)

**Answers should be a comprehensive proposal for a revised excerpt and wiki for the tag.** Alternatively, you should contribute to the community wiki answer with specific additions or improvements.

---

The current **excerpt** reads:

> Questions relating to situations involving management in the workplace.

---

The current **wiki** reads:

> This tag applies to:
>
> - questions about how situations are managed by ones superiors.
> - questions about how to manage a specific situation either before it
>     arises, or when one is dealing with the consequences.
>
> For example,
>   this tag will apply to questions about [why managers might want to keep it secret that an employee is leaving](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/why-would-managers-want-to-keep-it-top-secret-that-an-employee-is-leaving)

---

Here’s to more informative, comprehensive, and interesting tag wikis! Cheers!

Comment: Heh, I would not have made a meta post for this hehe, if I had a better, more comprehensive excerpt I would have edited the tag right there.... but good thing you did :)

Comment: But yeah, on a second thought good thing you wrote it, so we can reach consensus. In the case where tags are empty I think is more adequate to just proceed to add a description

Comment: This is a potentially substantial change to the interpretation of the tag (away from "the managers of an organization" and to "management of an organization") - at least I was hoping for some commentary on that. For edits that have less potential for conversation, I agree it's best just to make them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management)

---

### Excerpt

For questions about the tools and practices of management, including business management, project management, performance management and other management disciplines in the workplace.

---

### Wiki

**[Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management)** is the set of practices, tools, and theories employed in the administration and operation of an organization. Managers formally practice management, but all members of an organization may participate in management activities as part of their role regardless of title.

Management is practiced and studied across a number of sub-disciplines, including:

- [Performance management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_management): The systems and tools that enable managers and employees to measure and understand current performance and improve performance over time.
- [Human resource management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_resource_management): The strategic efforts to organize and administrate individuals in the workplace to maximize the performance of individuals and the organization
- [Project management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management): The administration of work, resources, and individuals within a team to accomplish the team’s goals.
- [Knowledge management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_management): The administration of creating, documenting, cataloging, and sharing knowledge within an organization.
- [Product management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_management): The administration of planning, forecasting, production, and marketing of a product.

#### Issues relevant to [management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management)

Managers and employees face a number of managerial challenges that are relevant to discussion on The Workplace, including:

- Identifying alternative management tools and practices to employ in situation at work
- Discussing the benefits and limitations of a specific management practice
- Recovering from a failure of management or unproductive management practices
- Experimenting with different management practices or testing out new theories
- Understanding the expectations and norms of a management role

You should **consider using a different tag if your question is about:**

- Discussing a situation involving a manager (possibly your direct manager) at a company (use [manager](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manager))
- Discussing a decision, policy, or action of the upper management of an organization (use [manager](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manager))

#### Related tags

[project-management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) [people-management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/people-management) [micro-management](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/micro-management)

#### Outside resources

- [Harvard Business Review](https://hbr.org/) - An online and print publication focused on the practice of management of all disciplines
- [MIT Sloan Management Review](https://sloanreview.mit.edu/) - An online publication similar to the Harvard Business Review

Comment: Seems like there should be a sub domain about "people management." In fact, I wonder if we should make it clear that *people management* is the focus of "management" in The Workplace context? I'd imagine that questions about Project, Product, or Knowledge management would probably attract VTC's for being off topic (and they probably belong on other SE sites anyways).

Comment: @dwizum, I added HR and performance management disciplines as people management doesn't (yet) have a clear definition across organizations.